# Do any of the other "Mane Six" have surnames?

Tags: my-little-pony-fim, my-little-pony

By-and-large, surnames seem to be completely ignored in My Little Pony: Friendship is Magic - with two exceptions that I can think of:

- [Mr. and Mrs. Cake](http://mlp.wikia.com/wiki/Mr._and_Mrs._Cake)
- [The Apple Family](http://mlp.wikia.com/wiki/Apple_family), though none of this family is ever referred (to my recollection, at least) by their first and last names. (It certainly would sound awkward saying "Applejack Apple".)

So, the concept of surnames or family names *does* exist in Equestria. What are the surnames of the other main characters?

Comment: Some other possible exceptions: [Mulia Mild](http://mlp.wikia.com/wiki/Mulia_Mild) and [Cranky Doodle Donkey](http://mlp.wikia.com/wiki/Cranky_Doodle_Donkey).

Comment: About the Apple Family, let me note that Granny Smith mentions “Smith family” in S2 E12 “Family Appreciation Day”.

Comment: @b_jonas was she referring to the family at the reunion? Could "Smith" be her un-married family name?

Comment: @phantom42: I guess the family just wasn't called the Apples before she has found the zap apple trees and Ponyville got founded.

Comment: Are the Mane Six like the Final Five in Battlestar?

Comment: I don't know about Fluttershy's surname, but, in "Flutter Brutter", you can see her parents, who their names aren't mentioned, and you can see her brother, known as "Zeffer Breeze". (I like to refer her family as the Shy family)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### They have family naming conventions — but not exactly *surnames*.

Both on-screen and in supplementary material and interviews, we get hints or outright information about some of their families' naming patterns. Sadly, some families are more mysterious than others, but it seems reasonable that the ones we don't *know* about yet do also have some kind of common moniker.

#### The Pies

At first this family seemed to come closest to having an actual surname. Pinkie Pie mentions her "Granny Pie" in the Laughter Song, and her sisters are Marble Pie and Limestone Pie (an interview with Faust revealed that Pinkie's sisters might have been named Mince Meat Pie and Chicken Pot Pie).

However, her parents are named after stones (Cloudy Quartz and Igneous Rock). Maybe they've got an every-other-generation thing going on? I got nothin'.

#### The Apples

This is the most obvious, and while "Apple" is definitively not a surname, it *is* clearly their family name and the common connection between their individual names. "Apple" is more like a clan name than a surname.

#### Rainbow Dash we aren't sure.

RD's past is shrouded in mystery. In flashbacks (particularly "Games Ponies Play") we've seen her associated with the adult pegasi Rainbowshine and Rainbow Blaze, and other media like collectible cards reinforce that relationship, but these ponies aren't named in the show itself. Presumably their family would share a "rainbow" naming convention.

#### Rarity we can't figure out.

Her mother seems to be based on two previous-generation ponies who have "Wish" in their names,but a mobile game calls her "Betty Bouffant" and Rarity's father "Magnum." And then there's Sweetie <s>Bot</s> Belle... this family doesn't have any obvious naming conceit.

#### Fluttershy we don't know.

Like, anything. At all. The girl's family is a closed book.

#### Twilight Sparkle's family is named for kinds of radiance.

Obviously we've got Sparkle, Twilight and Armor, Shining. Their mother was named Twilight Velvet in a mobile game and in mystery pack toys, while their father is nameless but seems partly based on a G1 German toy called Nachlicht (Nightlight).

[For the record, while Western names are often of the "given + sur" construction, many other cultures work differently. I personally live in a culture where [extended relations](http://guampedia.com/familia/) have a "familian" name in common, regardless of what surnames they each have: *familian babui* (the boar family) is a broad description of clan-like kinship. The Apple family naming convention reminds me of this.]

Comment: As for the Pies, I wonder if Peachy Pie is a relative.

Comment: @b_jonas If memory isn't wrong, in S4E9 the link between Pinkie Pie and Applejack is a distant relative called "Apple Pie"

Comment: In *Flutter Brutter*, Rainbow Dash addresses Fluttershy's parents as "Mr and Mrs Shy"

Comment: It would be cool to see this answer updated post-Season 7

Comment: Don't forget the Pears.

Answer (score 1):

Pinkie Pie's full name is Pinkamena Diane Pie. Applejack calls her that. Her sister is Maude Pie (probably a pun on mud pie). Naming is rather inconsistent in Equestria.